# Is there any way to check if a Bluetooth device is a Fitbit tracker using Android's Bluetooth APIs?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, fitbit

I've got a use-case where my Android app needs to check if a Bluetooth device is whether or not a Fitbit tracker, since this will trigger a specific flow in the app. I know that I can scan for Bluetooth devices available to connect to and that I can obtain certain data from them, such as name and alias, but I haven't found anything regarding how to specifically obtain the device's vendor. So I'd like to know if this is possible and if that's the case how can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the device name/vendor without connecting to the specific device, then as you said, you need to rely on the scan results to get the name of the device and then trigger the flow depending on the name of the device.

If you want to get the name/vendor during a connection, then your best bet is the [device information service](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/45899909/device-information-service-bluetooth-development-portal) (0x1800), which includes a few characteristics such as the manufacturer name. However, this service is optional and I'm not sure if Fitbits include it in their GATT table. You can find this out by connecting to the Fitbit (e.g. using nRF Connect app) and check the list of services/characteristics.

Below is a table of the available optional characteristics in the Device Information service:-

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful information, thank you.